# Цвет птички чекбокса и лейбла

Tags: html, css

Собственно, как сделать цвет флажка другим?

Comment: никак. Но можно обмануть пользователя https://codepen.io/Sambego/pen/zDLxe https://codepen.io/hansmaad/pen/qaGrQL

Comment: Странно, что никак, я видел макет, в котором чекбоксы отмечены другим цветом.

Comment: @BlackFire, то что вы видели, называется кастомный чекбокс и его можно реализовать одними средствами css, но можно и плагины применить. Внизу отличный пример кастомного чекбокса.

Answer (score 2):

Checkbox нельзя модифицировать, т.к он задается ОС. В таких случаях скрывают стандартный input и отображают кастомный со своими стилями.
Ниже пример как это делается:

```css
label input {
  display: none;/* <--скрываем дефолтный чекбокс */
}
label span {/* <-- стилизируем новый */
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#FFF;
  border-radius:2px;
  padding:3px;
}
[type=checkbox]:checked + span:before {/* <-- ставим иконку, когда чекбокс включен  */
  content: '\2714';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
  font-size:23px;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <span></span>
  Checkbox label text
</label>
```

отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css

Comment: Может, оттранслируете в css и добавите код в ответ?

Comment: @br3t мне так лень, что я нашел другой ответ проще на SO и немного локализовал)

Comment: Можно ли менять цвет кастомного Checkbox/ Например при отправке формы, сделать его неактивным визуально (сменив на серый цвет) к примеру?

Answer (score 0):

**Здравствуйте.**

Увидел этот вопрос, решил помочь, вдруг кто искал.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  accent-color: #d13b7b; 
}
```

> Вы можете посмотреть, где это работает, [здесь](https://caniuse.com/?search=accent-color) <--

*IE* не поддерживает !